# manually cleaning up thread-specific resources in boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++-cli, thread-local-storage

The boost thread static library cannot be used with C++/CLI code because it uses thread-local storage callbacks to clean up thread-specific data. It is possible to disable these callbacks by excluding tss_pe.obj when building the boost libraries, which allows the library to be used in managed code, but means that those resources need to be cleaned up manually.

None of this is officially documented, but I have pieced together from various bugs/forum posts (e.g. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1848) that this manual cleanup requires:

- calling on_thread_exit() when exiting a thread "not managed by boost::thread." I am unclear on exactly what this means, or why Boost thread would ever be responsible for cleaning up resources for a thread that it didn't manage.
- possibly also calling on_process_enter and on_process_exit at the beginning and end of main ( http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2007/11/130440.php ).

As a new user of the library who has not worked with thread-local storage before, I want to be sure I fully understand these terse guidelines. I'll be using boost thread from unmanaged code within a COM DLL that also contains a couple of managed classes.

Can someone provide a more verbose explanation, with examples, of the exact circumstances in which I need to call the above functions to avoid leaking resources when the automatic cleanup is disabled?

Comment: Since you appear to create a COM component anyway, rather then patching `boost::thread`, I'd recommend to use `std::thread` provided by Visual C++ (v110) implementation of the standard library...

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck using Visual Studio 2008 for unrelated reasons, so I can't use the C++11 threading features.

Comment: Then, separate your project into managed and unmanaged parts and communicate via binary safe APIs only. Use `boost::thread` in the unmanaged part at will, in the managed part use only .NET threading APIs...